# New embedded Google map turning gray at small sizes

Tags: css, google-maps, iframe, embed

I use this CSS code wrapped around iframes to make them responsive.

```
.responsive-iframe-container {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 56.25%; // This is the aspect ratio
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
}

.responsive-iframe-container iframe,   
.responsive-iframe-container object,  
.responsive-iframe-container embed {
 position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;

}
```

This still works for the new Google Maps, but when the map gets down to a certain size, it disappears and is replaced with a gray box. Inspecting it shows that Google is setting 'display:none' at that size for some reason. Is there a solution for this problem?

Please see this test scenerio:http://jsfiddle.net/kuLT6/

Comment: I don't think that this is a bug, I guess it's a feature to ensure that the map will not be displayed when the controls don't fit into the frame, especially the links at the bottom

Comment: I was afraid of that. What a terrible solution. If that's the case, they should 1) provide a link to view it full size or 2) actually hide it rather than leaving a gray box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm an absolute beginner so please bear in mind. Had the same problem and changed the padding-bottom to 80% and it worked. Issue almost certainly relates to the minimum space required for controls etc.

Only tried it at 80% as it worked for me that way. Might work at smaller % also.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @dr-mobile, it looks like a feature.

I was having the same problem in Firefox 26 on my Mac (Mavericks).

I was able to avoid the grey background by using a taller aspect ratio (your example is `16:9`).

It appears that the additional height allows Google's code to feel like it's got room to show all the UI bits.

Here's my `SCSS`:

```
.mm {

    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; // 16:9 = (9 / 16 = .5625) x 100
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px 0;

    iframe,
    object,
    embed,
    video {
        border: 0;
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 100% !important;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    &.tv { padding-bottom: 75%; } // 4:3 = (3 / 4 = .75) x 100

    &.slide { padding-bottom: 66.666%; } // 3:2 = (2 / 3 = .66666666666667) x 100

}
```

And the `HTML` (using the new Google Maps embed code):

```
<div class="mm tv"><iframe width="300" height="260" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m8!1m3!1d17819.243465772353!2d-122.4777661!3d37.8179015!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x808586deffffffc3%3A0xcded139783705509!2sGolden+Gate+Bridge!5e1!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1391366234135" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe></div>
```

Note that I'm using the `4:3` aspect ratio.

I've only tested Chrome and Firefox on my Mac, but it appears as though having the extra height makes it so the map can be viewed at smaller sizes.